# Notify other users who share the file

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried to find out with the SDK using appengine Python if a a file was starred. I used a service account for the authorisation. But the label starred is not shared. Is there a solution to see the starred files of other users or an easy way to notify other users. I do not use Google docs files.

Answer (score 0):

The `labels.starred` attribute is what you should be looking for in the file resource but this is of course a per-user setting (so for a file shared with 3 users, 2 may have it starred and this attribute show but the 3rd might not). If you're using a service account to impersonate the users you should be able to see who has the file starred by becoming them and looking for the attribute.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Comment: Becoming them? How can I do that?

Comment: I fount this, bit I'am not using a apps domain : https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation

Comment: then you'll need to go through regular OAuth 2.0 authentication, request access to the user's drive and then check.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Asking the user is not what need for my project. I think I have to use a domain or use a context menu app.